# Identify spammy application

Tags: spam

From time to time I get a window with spam on a Galaxy Tab 3.

If I press multitask key i get the name of the app is "Ads", but i don't have any app called "Ads".

My first question is why after pressing multitask key I cannot long press on the title of the thumbnail of the application to go to the application settings, and reveal its real name? (I can do that in a Nexus 6).

My second question is how to identify this application if I cannot fix previous question.

Comment: To 1: Compare the Android versions. Your Tab3 most likely runs some Android 4.x. The feature you refer to was introduced with 5.x AFAIR. To 2: Try our nice [search](/search?q=[spam]+popup+answers%3A1) feature, we had that topic a couple of times already. Also check [other questions tagged `spam`](/questions/tagged/spam), and you'll find related things like [Find what app is causing popups, NOT in notification bar](/q/63140/16575) ;)

Comment: Install [Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) to help track that application generating that *toast* message. Next step would be to uninstall that to see if the problem is fixed

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer, you have to enable developer mode for it to work.

Now I can click multitask button, then long press on the name of the app and it will take me to the application settings.

Note: The Galaxy Tab 3 is officially on Android 5.0.1